# Time dependent workflow should not fire after criteria field changed

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

I've two field `Date` and a Picklist field Named `Status` with value;`Active,Inactive,Pending`.

I've written a time based workflow rule .

Evaluation Criteria: Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria.(because it should not fire after changing the other data)

Criteria: Status = Active

Action :fire email 1 hr before Date.

now when criteria matched, workflow fired and action will be in the Queue and it will fire at 1 hr before scheduled date. Its working fine.

The requirement is, when action will in queue and in mean time when I've changed the `Status` field to `Inactive` then action should not be fired. because record is not active.

Please suggest the workaround. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Salesforce docs

> Example: Consider two rules that are identical, except the evaluation
>   criteria of Rule 1 is "On create only" and Rule 2 is "When a record is
>   created, and anytime it's edited to subsequently meet criteria." If
>   you create a record that matches both rules, Salesforce executes the
>   immediate actions and queues the time-dependent actions of both rules.
>   **If you then update the record and it no longer meets the rule
>   criteria, Salesforce removes the pending actions for both rules**. If
>   you then update the record so it meets the rule criteria again,
>   Salesforce only executes the actions associated with Rule 2.

So if your record doesn't match the criteria salesforce remove that action so you don't need to do anything.

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1)